# How to infer keyof Record<string, unknown[]> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have been reading "Programming TypeScript." In a chapter of the book, I faced this problem.

I am trying to implement a wrapper of EventEmitter, which has restrictions on the event names and it's arguments. The code uses Generics for reusability.

The code from the book:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'events'

class SafeEmitter<
  Events extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown[]>
> {
  private emitter = new EventEmitter
  emit<K extends keyof Events>(
    channel: K,
    ...data: Events[K]
  ) {
    return this.emitter.emit(channel, ...data)
  }
  on<K extends (keyof Events)>(
    channel: K,
    listener: (...data: Events[K]) => void
  ) {
    return this.emitter.on(channel, listener)
  }
}
```

The error:

```
(parameter) channel: K extends keyof Events
Argument of type 'K' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.
  Type 'keyof Events' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'.
    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol'.
        Type 'keyof Events' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
          Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
            Type 'keyof Events' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
              Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.ts(2345)
```

According to my quick googling, `keyof` operator always infer `string | symbol | number`. So I changed the code to infer string.

```js
on<K extends (keyof Events & string)>(
```

This works for the error above. However, I have got another error:

```
(parameter) listener: (...data: Events[K]) => void
Argument of type '(...data: Events[K]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Events[K]'.ts(2345)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem without type assertion.

---

(tsconfig.json)

```
{
  "include": ["./src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I have uploaded code on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-wildflower-00j1v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts&theme=dark)

Comment: I'm not getting the second error. What version of typescript are you running?

Comment: @WiseStrawberry Thanks for the comment! The version I'm using is `3.7.2`.  I'll put my tsconfig.json

Comment: `listener: (...data: Events[]) => void` does this not do what you want ?

Comment: Also, seeing as you're new to TypeScript, I would wager that building this yourself is more valuable, another implementation that is a bit easier can be found here:  https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/typed-event.html ( i actually use it one of my projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create a type-safe `EventEmitter` implementation, this should get you started:

```
import EventEmitter from "events";

type EventsOf<T> = keyof T & string;

type ListenerFunc<T, E extends EventsOf<T>> =
  T[E] extends (...args: any[]) => void ? T[E] : never;

type ListenerArgs<T, E extends EventsOf<T>> =
  T[E] extends (...args: infer A) => void ? A : never;

class SafeEmitter<T> extends EventEmitter {
  on<E extends EventsOf<T>>(event: E, listener: ListenerFunc<T, E>) {
    return super.on(event, listener);
  }

  once<E extends EventsOf<T>>(event: E, listener: ListenerFunc<T, E>) {
    return super.once(event, listener);
  }

  emit<E extends EventsOf<T>>(event: E, ...args: ListenerArgs<T, E>) {
    return super.emit(event, ...args);
  }
}

// === Let's test it! ===

interface MyEvents {
  started: () => void;
  received: (foo: string, bar?: number) => void;
}

class MyEmitter extends SafeEmitter<MyEvents> { }

const emitter = new MyEmitter();
emitter.on("started", () => console.log("started"));             // OK
emitter.on("received", (foo, bar) => console.log([foo, bar]));   // OK
emitter.on("invalid", () => false);                              // ERROR
emitter.emit("started");                                         // OK
emitter.emit("started", "ERROR!");                               // ERROR
emitter.emit("received");                                        // ERROR
emitter.emit("received", "FOO");                                 // OK
emitter.emit("received", "FOO", 42);                             // OK
emitter.emit("received", "FOO", "ERROR!");                       // ERROR
emitter.emit("invalid");                                         // ERROR
```

To answer your question, TypeScript is still often more strict than necessary when it comes to the assignability of `any[]` to unbounded generic types. In this particular case it fails to detect that the property values of `Events` must be arrays.

The only way around this that I have found is defining the event listener functions as actual methods on an `Events` interface, which is exactly what happens in the example above. As an added bonus, you also get to specify the event parameter names instead of defaulting to `data_0`, `data_1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using your `ListenerFunc` as the type of argument works for me.